# $T(f)(x) = -\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(f(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+f^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t$ is a contraction.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the application $T(f): C([0,1],[-1,1]) \to C([0,1],[-1,1])$

$$T(f)(x) = -\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(f(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+f^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t.$$

I already verified this application takes the unit ball in itself, but is it a contraction?

$\| T(f)-T(g) \| = \| -\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(f(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+f^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t +\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(g(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+g^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t \| \leq $

$\frac{1}{4} \| \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(g(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+g^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t  - \int_{0}^{x}\left( \sin(f(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (1+f^2 (s))\sin(s) \mathrm{d}s \right)\mathrm{d}t   \| $

But I don't know what can I do to appear $\| f-g \|$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your last inequality, we have $$\begin{align*}
|T(f)(x)-T(g)(x)|&\leq\frac{1}{4}\left| \int_0^x\left( \sin(g(t))-\sin(f(t)) + \int_{t/2}^{t} (g^2 (s)-f^2(s))\sin s\,ds\right)\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x|\sin(g(t))-\sin(f(t))|\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x
\int_{t/2}^{t}|g^2(s)-f^2(s)|\,ds\,dt.
\end{align*}
$$
But, $|\sin z-\sin w|\leq |z-w|$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb R$, so 
$$\begin{align*}
|T(f)(x)-T(g)(x)|&\leq\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x|g(t)-f(t)|\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x
\int_{t/2}^{t}|g(s)-f(s)||g(s)+f(s)|\,ds\,dt\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x\|g-f\|_{\infty}\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x
\int_{t/2}^{t}|g(s)-f(s)||g(s)+f(s)|\,ds\,dt\\
&\leq\frac{x}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x
\int_{t/2}^{t}|g(s)-f(s)|\,ds\,dt,
\end{align*}
$$
where we used that $|g(s)+f(s)|\leq |g(s)|+|f(s)|\leq 1+1=2$ at the last step. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
|T(f)(x)-T(g)(x)|&\leq\frac{x}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x
\int_{t/2}^{t}\|g-f\|_{\infty}\,ds\,dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}\left(x+2\int_0^x\int_{t/2}^t\,ds\,dt\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}\left(x+2\int_0^x\frac{t}{2}\,dt\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}\|g-f\|_{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&\leq\frac{3}{8}\|g-f\|_{\infty}.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore $\|Tf-Tg\|_{\infty}\leq\frac{3}{8}\|f-g\|_{\infty}$, so $T$ is a contraction.